# Java Android - Salvar Eventos

Tags: java, android

Como faço para salvar eventos em um APP java Android?por exemplo, um programa tem uma checkbox, eu o abro marco essa caixa e saio, quando retornar ela estará desmarcada.Como faço pra que a informação de que ela está checada seja salva?Obrigado.

Comment: dai depende, se você pega os itens da sua lista de uma tabela em um DB basta vce ter um campo nessa tabela indicando que tal item está marcado, agora se voce tem ous itens fixos em uma lista ou preenchidos de alguma outra forma voce vai precisará saber mais sobre "Preference" da api Settings, veja o link: (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Answer (score 1):

Pode se salvar no `SharedPreferences`!

Segue um exmeplo:

```
   /**
     * CONSTANTES
     */
    private String CONFIGRACOES = "#CONFIGRACOES";
    private String CONFIGRACOES_ITEM_1 = "#CONFIGRACOES.ITEM_1";
    private String CONFIGRACOES_ITEM_2 = "#CONFIGRACOES.ITEM_2";


    public Configuracoes getConfiguracoes(final Context mContext){
        if(null == mContext) return null;
        //Cria uma instancia do SharedPreferences
        final SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(CONFIGRACOES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // se for nulo, n˜ao temos mais o que fazer, e retornamos nulo!
        if(null == prefs) return null;


        /**
         *  Cria uma nova instacia e coleta os valores!
         *  Para carregar um valor passamos o nome da Propriedade e um valor padrão.
         *  Se não haver dados para esta propriedade, ele irá retornar o valor padão
         */

        final Configuracoes config = new Configuracoes();
        config.setItem1(prefs.getBoolean(CONFIGRACOES_ITEM_1, false));
        config.setItem2(prefs.getBoolean(CONFIGRACOES_ITEM_2, false));

        return config;
    }


    /**
     * Grava as informações do objeto em um SharedPreferences.
     */
    public void setUser(final Configuracoes configuracoes, final Context mContext){
        if(null == configuracoes) return;
        //Cria uma instancia do SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(CONFIGRACOES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Criamos um instancia do editor, para salvamos os dados
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(CONFIGRACOES_ITEM_1, configuracoes.getItem1());
        editor.putBoolean(CONFIGRACOES_ITEM_2, configuracoes.getItem2());
        // Para que as informações sejam atualizadas
        editor.apply();
    }


    /**
     * Objeto que encapsula as informações que serão armazenadas
     */
    class Configuracoes{
        Boolean item1;
        Boolean item2;

        public Boolean getItem1() {
            return item1;
        }

        public void setItem1(Boolean item1) {
            this.item1 = item1;
        }

        public Boolean getItem2() {
            return item2;
        }

        public void setItem2(Boolean item2) {
            this.item2 = item2;
        }
    }
```

[Segue a documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)